# Is BIOS used after OS fully loaded?

Tags: bios

Obviously, I can't get to the BIOS after the OS is loaded.

But is it somehow possible to invoke BIOS functionality/interact with it from within the OS? Does the OS do it?
Is it possible for a user mode applications? (all of this in protected mode, because I've read it's possible in real mode.)

Or is the BIOS only needed before the OS loads?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on a few things.  For starters on the OS.

- If you boot DOS (ancient, I know) then DOS will do most of its jobs via BIOS calls.
- If you use a modern OS then that will generally take over control from the BIOS.

Secondly, do you consider ACPI part of the BIOS?
That part keeps on running even after a modern OS is loaded).

Comment: DOS (or OpenDOS) boots are not completely obsolete. Diagnostics often run that way.